# Undefined method update_attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, update-attributes

Im trying to allow the user to update the attributes for a single column for multiple elements based on a drop down (with `name="status`) but i keep getting back the error: `undefined method 'update_attributes'`. Any suggestions?

```
 def supdate
        @input_messages = InputMessage.find(params[:message_ids])
        respond_to do |format|
          if @input_messages.update_attributes(:status => params[:status])
          format/html { redirect_to :action => "show" }
          end
        end
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your `params[:message_ids]` value is an array, then `@input_messages` will be an array of results instead of a single ActiveRecord object. You may need to do something like this instead:

```
@input_messages.each do |input_message|
  input_message.update_attributes(:status => params[:status])
end
```