# Rails 'best in place gem', update only one row

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, best-in-place

I am using the Best in Place gem with a rails 4 app, and have multiple records from a database table which is displayed to the user. Initially, my DB didn't update, but with [Undefined method update_attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7230461/undefined-method-update-attributes) solution my DB now updates.

My current problem is: When the user edits a particular row, i want that row in the database to be updated. Right now the updated field causes all rows to be updated in the DB.

Here is the code for table which I want the user to edit that is rendered in the view:

```
<tbody>

<% @userdailydata.each do |data| %>
<tr>
<td> <%= best_in_place data, :date,:display_with => lambda { |v| v.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") }  %> </td>
<td> <%= best_in_place data, :calories_consumed %> </td>
<td> <%= best_in_place data, :calories_exercised %> </td>
<td> <%= best_in_place data, :weight %> </td>
</tr> 
<% end %>
</tbody>
```

Update action from controller:

```
def update
@userdailydata = Userdailydata.where(:user_id=>current_user.id)
respond_with @userdailydata
@userdailydata.each do |data|
   data.update_attributes(allowed_params)
end
end
```

This code is looping through each row exposed to the user and updating all the rows (instead of the one row in question), so I know why my current code is incorrect, but I am unsure how to fix this.

Can someone help me figure out how to only update the record being actively edited by the user?

Comment: is this the code from your controller's `update` action? I would suggest to post the whole code of the action. and code in the views

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I edited the question and provided some more code.

Comment: I think your `update` action code is incorrect. you want to update the user's attributes ( in other words, user's data). right? the view you posted above, is it from `users.index.html.erb`?

Comment: Yes, the view is from use userdailydata.index.html.erb. I want to update the user's data from whatever date the user performs inline editing on. But a whole table of data with many dates is exposed to the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your `update` action should look like this:

```
def update
  @userdailydata = Userdailydata.find(params[:id]) #first, find the specific user by id
  #maybe, @userdailydata = Userdailydata.where(:user_id=>current_user.id) can replace the line above. they seem to be doing the same thing. 
  #the goal is fetch a specific user to edit it's attributes. 
  respond_to do |format|
    if @userdailydata.update(allowed_params) # i'm assuming you got allowed_params set up properly
       format.html { redirect_to @userdailydata }
       format.json { respond_with_bip(@userdailydata) }
   else
       format.html { render :action => "edit" }
       format.json { respond_with_bip(@userdailydata) }
   end
 end
end
```

only the params you pass in will be updated. Not necessary all of the params.

if you are editing, say, `users show page`, you'll change the above code to:

```
<tbody>


<tr>
<td> <%= best_in_place data @userdailydata, :date,:display_with => lambda { |v| v.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") }  %> </td>
<td> <%= best_in_place data @userdailydata, :calories_consumed %> </td>
<td> <%= best_in_place data @userdailydata, :calories_exercised %> </td>
<td> <%= best_in_place data @userdailydata, :weight %> </td>
</tr> 
</tbody>
```

see here, you'll only be inline-editing the specific `attributes`that you want to edit.

Comment: at `if @userdailydata.update(allowed_params)`  I get the error 'wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)' when I try to debug. My allowed_params code is `def allowed_params
  params.require(:userdailydata).permit(:weight,:calories_consumed, :calories_exercised, :date, :user_id)
end` .

Comment: your `allowed_params` looks good. What is the line before that? is it `@userdailydata = Userdailydata.find(params[:id])`?

Comment: another question,about this line: `<% @userdailydata.each do |data| %>`: how is `@userdailydata` that you trying to loop through in the `index view` defined? post that. If `@userdailydata` holds attributes for `one user`, I don't think you can iterate through. Unless it is an `array of multiple users' daily data`

Comment: I tried both `@userdailydata = Userdailydata.find(params[:id])` as well as my original `@userdailydata = Userdailydata.where(:user_id=>current_user.id)`. @user daily data is defined as in the index action as `@userdailydata = Userdailydata.where(:user_id=>current_user.id)`, so I get a table of daily data for a unique user. I am able to iterate through the data to expose it in a view. That part displays fine. The only problem is updating only one of the records in the DB (and not all of them for that particular user)

Comment: in your update action, if you use the code in my example (with the first line being: `@userdailydata = Userdailydata.find(params[:id])` ), is the edit action working without using `best_in_place`? can you post the `UserDailyData` and the `User` models

Comment: All set, marking your answer as correct. Once I restarted the web server your original suggestion worked. Apologies for not trying that earlier!